# Can you change camera view in Resident Evil 6?

Tags: resident-evil-6

Is it possible to change the distance of the camera view in RE6 ?? I feel it's a bit too zoomed in, and would like to zoom out a bit for a better view.

Comment: http://www.shacknews.com/article/76357/resident-evil-6-patch-adds-adjustable-camera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Camera can't be changed in game for whatever stupid reason. You have to go to main menu and select "camera" from the options.

The bottom selections (three of them) deal with depth and the like. You can go to default which is 0 or move it up to 15 the pull the camera back more.